# How to get a 2d array to print from 1 to 80

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The goal for my program is for a 2d array to print from 1 to 80. I am trying to get it to look sort of like this.

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
```

I can fix the formating and everything later but how do i get the 2d array to print the numbers from 1-80? I have attached the code that i have done so far.

public class Conversion
    {

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        int[][] twoarray = new int[8][10];

        int i ;
        int j ;

        for(i =0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            twoarray[i][j] = (i * j);
        }


        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {

                System.out.print(i);
                System.out.print("  ");
                System.out.print(j);
                System.out.print("  ");


            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code does not even use the filled in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more clarification

```
    for(i =0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        twoarray[i][j] = (i * 10+j+ 1);
    }
    /* when i=0, j=0, value is 0*10+0+1=1 -->1st Row
         when i=0, j=1, value is 0*10+1+1=2 --> 1st Row
         when i=7,j=0, value is 7*10+0+1=71 --> 8th Row
         when i=7, j=9, value is 7*10+9+1=80 --> 8th Row */
```

**Update:** How to do it using 1-D array

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    int array[]=new int[80];

    //filling array upto 80
    for(int i=0;i<=79;i++) 
        array[i]=i+1;

    //display array on console
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=79;i++)
    {
        counter++;
        System.out.print(array[i]+" ");

        if(counter==10)
        {
            /*printing new line
            after counting upto 10 elements*/
            System.out.println(); 

            //reseting counter to 0;
            counter=0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**
However the first row may not be aligned with rows below because elements in first row are one digit so there is little space glitch, which can be solved easily but I don't think it would be problem for you, as you just want to print 8  rows and 10 columns.

[image]

Comment: Sat sri akal. Do you know how i could transfer this 2d array into a 1d array and still get the same output? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: sat sri akal ji! sure you can. that will be easier than this, will update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're initializing the array incorrectly

```
twoarray[i][j] = (i * j);
```

should be

```
twoarray[i][j] = (i * 10 + j + 1);
```

As a side note, this is very similar to how you calculate the memory address (memory offset) of a pixel on the screen, given it's X and Y coordinates, and the screen width.

Then to actually use the 2d array

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(twoarray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `twoarray[i][j] = (i * 10 + j+1);`

Comment: Good catch... I'm used to calculating 0-based memory offsets :-)

Answer (score 0):

The output I get from this code is the same as what you want in your question.

Please note that the output console has this weird format where the first line is not aligned with the rest. If you output it to a text area component it should look fine. Your problem is that you forgot to count the actual value to the array. Instead you tried to multiply the value with your counters. Your counters in this program will just be that, counters. Hope this works out for you :)

```
public class Conversion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] twoArray = new int[8][10];

    int i; // i & j are just counters to iterate through your array
    int j;
    int sum = 0; // This will keep track of the sum/ counting from 1 to 80

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){ 
        for (j = 0; j<10; j++){
            sum+= 1; // Increment with its own value + 1. Therefor it is counting.
            twoArray[i][j] = (sum);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(j=0; j< 10;j++){
                System.out.print(twoArray[i][j]); //Unload the array.
                System.out.print(" ");  
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the 1D Array version:

Only use this if you REALLY REALLY REALLY need the array because it is rather redundant since you can just print directly to the console(check the commented out code).

```
public class Conversion {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] numbers = new int[80];

   int count = 0;

    for (int K = 0; K<80; K++) {
        count+= 1;
        numbers[K] = count;
    }

    count = -1;//reinitialize count.
    for (int L = 0; L<8; L++){
        System.out.println("");
        for (int M = 0; M<10; M++){

            count+= 1;

            if(count == 80){
                return;
            }else {
                System.out.print(numbers[count] + " ");
            } 
        }
    }


  /*  int count = 0; //reinitialize count. You can get the same results by just using the code here 
                                          //if you really need the array then use the un-commented code.
    for (int L = 0; L<8; L++){
        System.out.println("");
        for (int M = 0; M<10; M++){
            count+= 1;
            System.out.print(" " + count);
        }
    }*/
}
```

}

Comment: Also you need to use your array for the actual output.

Comment: Do you know how i could do this with a 1d array. One of my friends told me i could transfer this 2d array into a 1d array and still have the same output? Do you know how to do that?   Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @John Jack hey If you have found an answer that worked for you please mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a 2D array or even a 1D array. Here's the code.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int r = 8, c = 10; //You can change this
        int[][] toArray = new int[r][c]; //using 2D array
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){ //i is the ten's place
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++){ //j is the one's place
                toArray[i][j] = i*10 + j + 1;
                System.out.print(toArray[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n\n");

        int a[] = new int[r*c]; //using 1D array
        for(int i = 0; i < r*c; i++){
            a[i] = (i+1); //+1 since we're starting with 1
            System.out.print(a[i]+"\t");
            if(a[i]%10==0) //Go to the next line if number is 10, 20, 30,..
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Off course, there is no need for the array in this program and you can directly print the values.